# how to use factory/service for sharing information between multiple controllers in angularjs?

Tags: http, angularjs, controllers

Im trying to load a JSON when app starts, and spread the data between all my controllers.
I know this is not very hard to do, but Im confused from all articles/answers I've read because they use different syntax than I do, can someone Please direct me on how to to that?

Im currently making the controller make the $http.get :

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp", [])

myApp.controller "HomeCtrl", ($scope, $http, $routeParams) ->
 $http.get('gethome.php').success (data) ->
  $scope.home = data
```

But I have to repeat myself in each and every controller I want to have access to that Data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will recommend you using Memoization pattern along with service and reuse the service in the controller

Pls check the below sample code

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

          app.service('cache', function ($http,$q) {
              var mycache={};
              return {
                  getdata: function (key) {
                      var deferred = $q.defer();
                      if (mycache[key]) {
                          deferred.resolve(mycache[key]);
                      }
                      else {
                          $http.get('TextFile.txt').then(function (data) {
                              mycache[key] = data.data;
                              deferred.resolve(mycache[key]);
                          });
                      }
                      return deferred.promise;
                  }
              }
          });


          app.controller('test', function ($scope, cache) {
              cache.getdata('cache').then(function (data) {
                  $scope.data = data;
              });
         });

           app.controller('test1', function ($scope, cache) {
              //since data is already cached now it will server the cached data
              cache.getdata('cache').then(function (data) {
                  $scope.data = data;
              });
         });
```

Comment: Ajay, thank you but can you explain that code? Or simplify it alittle

Comment: Basically angular service are singleton instance .So when you call the service first time mycahe will be empty then we make a ajax hit and fetch the data and assign to mycahe .The next time you call a service mycache will not be empty so it will directly return the result added to mycache so there will be no requirement of making new ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You can access to `$scope` with :

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('YourCtrl')).scope();
```

After, you can init `data` in all your controllers.

Comment: OK but you want access to `Controller`, I propose a solution ;)