# Angularjs automatically refresh controllers using Shared Service

Tags: angularjs

After much research I found the following answer, which closely matched my code and explained clearly how to share data between controllers using a shared service (with caching and promises).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17472995/2341148

However, this answer (and all others I can find) do not show how to keep each controller in sync.  When something changes in one controller I want the other controller(s) to reload/refresh their data.

For example, say controller "test" submits some data to the server to update a user name. Now controller "test1" displays a different name because it has its own scope. What can be done to make "test1" reload the service to get the most recent data (without refreshing the entire page)?

Can someone extend this code to make test reload the service when test1 changes data?

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

      app.service('cache', function ($http,$q) {
          var mycache={};
          return {
              getdata: function (key) {
                  var deferred = $q.defer();
                  if (mycache[key]) {
                      deferred.resolve(mycache[key]);
                  }
                  else {
                      $http.get('TextFile.txt').then(function (data) {
                          mycache[key] = data.data;
                          deferred.resolve(mycache[key]);
                      });
                  }
                  return deferred.promise;
              }
          }
      });


      app.controller('test', function ($scope, cache) {
          cache.getdata('cache').then(function (data) {
              $scope.data = data;
          });
     });

       app.controller('test1', function ($scope, cache) {
          //since data is already cached now it will server the cached data
          cache.getdata('cache').then(function (data) {
              $scope.data = data;
          });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I shoot out an event from the service. Looks kind of like this.

```
.service("Data", function($http, $rootScope) {
  var this_ = this, 
      data;

  $http.get(some_url, function(response) {
    this_.set(response.data);
  }

  this.get = function() {
    return data;
  }

  this.set = function(data_) {
    data = data_;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:data-change');
  }

});
```

And the controllers communicate to the service like this

```
$rootScope.$on('event:data-change', function() {
    $scope.data = Data.get();
}

$scope.update = function(d) {
  Data.set(d);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  I'm not sure how that goes into the code I posted, but it seems like the relevant bits are "$broadcast" and "$on".  The service can broadcast to the controllers each time something calls it.  Isn't there an automatically or simple way to make your controllers reload in Angularjs?

Comment: This shows how to update your controllers using $broadcast from a service. Any time the service's set() method is called, all controllers listening for the broadcast will be updated.